# Simple Inheritance issue with my model

Tags: java, android, inheritance, gson

In my app I get `JSON` data in this format

```
{
    "data": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
    },
    "success": true
}
```

I'm using `gson` to parse it to object, here is the model I have:

```
public class ApiResponse {
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("errormsg")
    @Expose
    private String errormsg;

    /**
     * @return The success
     */
    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * @param success The success
     */
    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    /**
     * @return The errormsg
     */
    public String getErrormsg() {
        return errormsg;
    }

    /**
     * @param errormsg The errormsg
     */
    public void setErrormsg(String errormsg) {
        this.errormsg = errormsg;
    }

}
```

I will always get the `success` key and if its true then `data` will be there if not then `errormsg` instead.

Now the `data` key in my `JSON` is my actual model.

Since all models have the above properties, I am looking for a way I can `extend` that class.

for example:

```
public class MyModel extends ApiResponse{}
```

so that I can do :

```
myModel.getData().getKey1();
```

I tried to override `getData()` but the model will be different so I was able to find the solution.

I could use nested class but I will have to repeat this properties and add my real model as a nested class.

How can I make my models inherit the same common properties.

Also `data` could be an object or a list of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics to solve this problem. 
To be more specific - you should define base class abstract,  like this

```
public abstract class ApiResponse<T> {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private T mData;

    public T getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    //common code - success, etc.
}
```

And then you can define concrete request classes like this:

```
public class MyResponse extends ApiResponse<MyData> {

}
```

And

```
getData()
```

method, called on MyResponse object will return parsed MyData. Of course, you should mark all parsable fields in MyData class.

Keep in mind, inherited model class will expect all fields for serialization/deserialization from base class, so you should keep things clean and limit inheritance depth as much as possible.

Comment: please explain why you used `ApiResponse<List<String>>`

Comment: It is just an example, you mentioned, data can be and object as well. So, you can replace List<String> with any other class you beed as model.

Comment: I also suggest you to look through sources of ArrayList, for example, to understand how generics work

Comment: Im sure your answer is correct, just dont know how to implement it. Im getting a classcastexception when gson parser tries to convert it. here is how I tried it http://pastebin.com/JW1jqjzQ

Comment: Sorry, you are on right way, but it's an error in my example, please see edited answer. Also you should make nested Data class actually inner (add static before class) to allow gson instantiate it separately from ApiResponse class. If this will not work, could you post full sracktrace of exception? I have only phone now, so can't actually check...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101099/discussion-between-cool-do-and-alexander-semenov).